# Access static method from GenericClass<T> where T is given by a Type instance

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, static

I have a generic class with a static method, that method using the type parameter:

```
GenericClass<T>
{
    public static void Method()
    {
        //takes info from typeof(T)
    }
}
```

Now, I need to access that static method, but not simply using `GenericClass<KnownType>.Method()`. I need to do this having a Type instance. So:

```
public void OutsiderMethod(Type T)
{
    GenericClass<T>.Method() 
    //it's clear this line won't compile, for T is a Type instance
    //but i want some way to have access to that static method.
}
```

Using reflections, I probably can get a way to invoke that method by it's string name, using some MethodInfo stuff.
That is partially good, solves the question. 
But if possible, I'd love to have not to use the name as string.

Anyone???

Comment: Wouldn't an extension method be more appropriate for this situation?

Comment: That would require an instance of GenericClass<T>, with T given by Type instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generic methods of non-generic classes are easier to access than non-generic methods of generic classes.

You can create a helper method that simply calls the real method:

```
void OutsiderMethodHelper<T>()
{
    GenericClass<T>.Method();
}
```

You can then get the `MethodInfo` for that method without looking it up by name-as-string:

```
public void OutsiderMethod(Type T)
{
    Action action = OutsiderMethodHelper<object>;
    action.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(T).Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: hmmm, that sounds good!! I'll test it. Meanwhile, newbie questions: is there a real need to create the delegate??? And why `GetGenericMethodDefinition` when `MakeGenericMethod` is present in `Method`???

Comment: Is there a Reflection literature I can find to learn it better?

Comment: @Daniel There are not that many situations where C# allows you to refer to a function without calling it, creating a delegate is one such situation, and probably the easiest. The delegate is for `OutsiderMethodHelper<object>`, `GetGenericMethodDefinition()` gives you the `MethodInfo` for `OutsiderMethodHelper<>`, and `MakeGenericMethod` allows you to fill in the type argument. You'll get an exception if you skip the `GetGenericMethodDefinition()`, because `OutsiderMethodHelper<object>` does not have any generic type arguments that need to be filled.

Comment: @Daniel I'd say "Just try it". The reflection properties and functions are well-behaved, and will almost always let you know when you're doing something wrong, with an exception with a useful description. That's how I picked it up, anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the *Expression*:

```
public static class GenericHelper
{
    public static object Invoke(Expression<Action> invokeMethod, object target, Type genericType, params object[] parameters)
    {
        MethodInfo methodInfo = ParseMethodExpression(invokeMethod);
        if (!methodInfo.DeclaringType.IsGenericType)
            throw new ArgumentException("The method supports only generic types");
        Type type = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(genericType);
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodInfo.Name);
        return method.Invoke(target, parameters);
    }

    public static object Invoke(Expression<Action> invokeMethod, Type genericType, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return Invoke(invokeMethod, null, genericType, parameters: parameters);
    }

    private static MethodInfo ParseMethodExpression(LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        Validate.ArgumentNotNull(expression, "expression");
        // Get the last element of the include path
        var unaryExpression = expression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if (unaryExpression != null)
        {
            var memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MethodCallExpression;
            if (memberExpression != null)
                return memberExpression.Method;
        }
        var expressionBody = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (expressionBody != null)
            return expressionBody.Method;
        throw new NotSupportedException("Expession not supported");
    }
}
```

The method call will be look like this:

```
GenericHelper.Invoke(() => GenericClass<object>.Method(), typeof(string));
```